# Google Places API - Get all places in Google Maps that have XYZ in its name

Tags: google-places-api

I'm trying get a list of all places in Germany that are related to a given topic. First place to start was Google Places API - text search, but it only returned 20 results at most.

curl -X POST -d '{
"textQuery" : "Bananabread, Germany"
}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'X-Goog-Api-Key: API_KEY' -H 'X-Goog-FieldMask: places.displayName,places.formattedAddress' 'https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places:searchText'

The maxCound output seems to be 20 based on the documentation. Hence I thinking of using locationBias parameter to run the call several time for small section of Germany based on long/lat.